# Objective-C: Make TextView Expand From Top Instead Of Bottom

Tags: objective-c, textview, uitextview

I have a UITextView in my .mm file. I added this code which is successful in vertically expanding the textView when the text reaches the end of the line -

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    [self onTextChange:textView.text];
}
```

However, the textView expands from the bottom, and instead I would like it to expand from the top (so that the bottom of the textView is always in the same position, like most messaging apps).

Is it possible to achieve this within the code I have already written? I am quite new to Objective-C and any input is hugely appreciated.

Comment: You need to recalculate `newFrame.origin` too. `newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(x: textView.frame.origin.x, y: textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.height - newSize.height)` or something like that. You need to do some recalculation.

Comment: This worked wonders. Very simple. Thank you.